# Setting Nexus auth token from the commandline

Tags: npm, nexus

I figured this would be a problem that has been solved a million times over, but I just can't find the solution.  I wish to setup my Java Maven project to install Angular dependencies from my private Nexus server.  I use the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to install a new npm every time, so the configuration must be available for that npm for it to work.

I know I can add the following to my .npmrc file and it works:

```
registry = http://nexus.global.dns/repository/npm-all/
_authToken = NpmToken.xxx
always-auth = true
```

The problem I have with this solution is that the auth token gets checked into git and that I have to remove it every time I work outside of my network, where I do not have access to the nexus server.  This happens for example when I am developing something for the frontend away from home as my nexus server is not on the cloud. So I wish for nexus to be used only by my jenkins pipelines which will use the frontend-maven-plugin.

I figured I would set the registry the commandline way but that is proving to be a challenge.  In my frontend-maven-plugin I have set up executions that run the following lines:

```
npm set registry http://nexus.global.dns/repository/npm-all/
npm //nexus.global.dns/:_authToken=${NEXUS_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}
npm install --no-package-lock
```

This returns a 401 error as it is not able to authenticate: `Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"`

My next attempt was to remove the explicit mention of the repository I want to use from Nexus, because maybe it can figure out which one it should use:

```
npm set registry http://nexus.global.dns
npm //nexus.global.dns/:_authToken=${NEXUS_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}
npm install --no-package-lock
```

Authentication now seemingly works, but it is trying to pull the dependencies from http://nexus.global.dns as expected.  I get the following error: `404 Not Found - GET http://nexus.global.dns/@angular-builders%2fjest`

If I navigate to `http://nexus.global.dns/repository/npm-all/@angular-builders%2fjest` instead I do get the dependency's package.json as a response.

Clearly the registry should be `http://nexus.global.dns/repository/npm-all/` but I can't get authentication to work with the command line.  I have also tried:

```
npm //nexus.global.dns/repository/npm-all/:_authToken=${NEXUS_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}
```

but this does not work either.  How do I set the auth token for my Nexus private server through the command line?

Comment: I threw in the towel on this one a while ago and did away with running my Angular tests within my Maven build pipeline.  I no longer use the frontend-maven-plugin and instead run the Angular tests in a separate command in the Jenkins pipeline, using the global npm config.  It's a pity but it does seem to be more efficient in terms of memory usage when running my pipelines.   I will leave the question open in case someone does have a solution.

Comment: I know you've given up on this one - but where did you put your .npmrc file? Is it reading it from your home directory or is it in the project? For some reason, the plugin won't read one from either of those locations for me. I'm having a similar issue to you, and just getting that working seemed like a good place to start at least..